# Security scanning has flagged Sonarqube as not disabling the AutoComplete attribute on password field

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube 5.3

A recent security scan of our SonarQube server from our IT department states:

"AutoComplete Attribute Not Disabled for Password in Form Based Authentication"

I've tested this out in 3 different browsers (FF, Chrome, IE 11) and none of them autocomplete the password (although FF does autocomplete the login id).

- Is there anything I can configure in SonarQube to satisfy the scanner?
- Does SonarQube take any other steps that prevent auto-completion of passwords, so that this can be flagged as a false positive?

Cheers,
Dave

Scanner complained about this code:

```js
<form id="login_form" action="/sessions/login" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="return_to_anchor" value="">
<h1 class="maintenance-title text-center">Log In to SonarQube</h1>
<div class="big-spacer-bottom">
<label for="login" class="login-label">Login</label>
<input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="login-input" maxlength="255" required
placeholder="Login">
</div>
<p class="big-spacer-bottom">
<label for="password" class="login-label">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="login-input" required
placeholder="Password">
</p>
<p class="big-spacer-bottom">
<input class="login-remember-me" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
<label for="remember_me"></label>
<label for="remember_me">Remember me on this computer</label>
</p>
<p class="text-right">
<button name="commit">Log in</button>
<a class="spacer-left" href="/">Cancel</a>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using to do this security scan?

Comment: Also, 5.3 is nearly 1.5 yrs old. The current version is 6.3 (6.4 out any day now) and the current LTS is 5.6.6.

Comment: We are using Qualys Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

I second Ann's question, which tool did you used ?

I've just checked and SonarQube 5.3 does have the parameter autocomplete=off on login page. So I'm wondering if you are talking about another page or if it's a false positive of a security scan.

Comment: I updated the description with the code that is being flagged by the scanner.  Does it differ from what you are seeing on the login page?

Comment: @DavidM indeed the parameter `autocomplete=off` is not present in your snippet. 
I'm wondering which browser Qualys Enterprise is simulating that may make this parameter not appearing (I've found some information here : https://community.qualys.com/thread/15701) 
I'll try to look at this at the beginning of next week.